# How to generate plain text reports with (fixed-width) tables

Tags: template-engine, text-processing, fixed-width

I'm looking to easily define forms with fixed-width output. Most of my forms end up looking something like this:

```
     [title]
text
some more text

A   B     CDE       E
-------------------------------
1   2     text      text
3   4.50  text      text

some more text
```

With all output being plain text.

Since there are many different (and yet similar) forms, I'd like to use a templating engine with a simple interface for generating fixed-width textual tables. Are there engines which support easily creating such tables? Or perhaps other ways to generate such tables?

Comment: How do you get to nearly 16K without learning that recommendation questions are **explicitly off-topic**?

Comment: @AndrewMedico: They are? I never noticed. I'm guessing it wouldn't help if I reworded it to "Which template engines support this scenario?" or something like that?

My main issue is that I couldn't find a single one that supports this sort of thing without some really strange syntax.

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254393/what-exactly-is-a-recommendation-question

Comment: @AndrewMedico: I've edited the question accordingly. I think it's better now; do you agree?

Comment: A more concrete question would be: "here is my input 
data, this is how I want the output to look. How do I do that?"

Comment: Any reason for not using a ReportWriter (e.g. JasperReports / https://community.jaspersoft.com/project/jaspersoft-studio) ???